# Two way binding in angular js with ng-src

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Upon calling `changeMainMedia` function, *current* value should change and then `ng-src="{{array[current].src}}"` should also change but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id="media-gallery" class="small reveal text-center media-gallery" data-reveal>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="main-media">
            <img ng-bind="current" class="main-gallery media-gallery-main" ng-src="{{array[current].src}}" / </div>

            <hr>

            <div class="nested-media">
                <img ng-click="changeMainMedia($index)" ng-repeat="obj in array" class="thumbnail media-gallery-thumbnail" ng-src="{{obj.src}}" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close reveal" type="button">
       <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
    </button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("mediaGallery", []);
    app.controller("mediaGalleryCtrl", ['$scope', function(scope) {
        var array = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            array.push({
                src: "gallery/image (" + i + ").jpg"
            });
        }

        scope.array = array;
        scope.current = 0;

        scope.changeMainMedia = function(index) {
            this.current = index;
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be change `current` scope variable

```
scope.changeMainMedia = function(index) {
    this.current = index
}
```

should be

```
scope.changeMainMedia = function(index) {
    scope.current = index;
}
```

---

Rather you could have selected image inside another scope variable, when user clicks on image like `ng-click="selectedImage = obj"`

**Markup**

```
<div class="main-media">
    <img ng-bind="current" class="main-gallery media-gallery-main" 
      ng-src="{{selectedImage.src}}"/> 
    <hr>
    <div class="nested-media">
        <img ng-click="selectedImage = obj" ng-repeat="obj in array" class="thumbnail media-gallery-thumbnail" ng-src="{{obj.src}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```